# Prove uniqueness in weak limit in linear normed space $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a weakly convergent sequence in $(X, ||\cdot||)$. Prove that the weak limit is unique.

> *Proof*. Suppose $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ and $x$ is not unique. Therefore, there must be at least **two** distinct weak limits which we will denote $x$ and $\tilde{x}$, respectively. Define sequences $a_n = f(x_n)$ and so $a = f(x)$ and $\tilde{a} = f(\tilde{x})$ with $$a_n \rightarrow a, \quad a_n \rightarrow \tilde{a}. $$
> These are strictly in $\mathbb{R}$. As they furthermore are convergent, for any $\varepsilon/2$ there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon/2$ for all $n \geq N$. Analogously, for any $\varepsilon/2$ there must be a $\tilde{N} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - \tilde{a}| < \varepsilon/2$ for all $n \geq \tilde{N}$. $$$$
> Let $\mathcal{N} = \max\{N,\tilde{N}\}$ and so $|a_n - a| < \varepsilon/2$ and $|a_n - \tilde{a}| < \varepsilon/2$ for any $n \geq \mathcal{N}$. It shall therefrom be noted that
> $$|a-\tilde{a}| \leq |a - a_n + a_n - \tilde{a}| \leq |a_n - a| + |a_n - \tilde{a}| < \varepsilon$$
> for sufficiently large $n$ (we have shown that there is such $n \geq \mathcal{N}$). As $\varepsilon$ may be made arbitrarily small, so can the distance $|a-\tilde{a}|$ which shows that $a = \widetilde{a}$, i.e the weak limit is unique.

QED? (Not QED)

**- EDIT/UPDATE I -**

From Kreyszig; as $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a sequence of real numbers, it must be unique, wherefore $f(x) = f(\tilde{x})$. It follows from the theorem

> If a sequence of **real** numbers $a_n$ has a limit, then this limit must be unique.

**- EDIT/UPDATE II -**

$f$ must be a linear functional, so $f(x) = f(\tilde{x})$ yields $f(x - \tilde{x}) = 0$. It then follows from corollary (4.3.4 p.223 Kreyszig) that if $f(x - \tilde{x})=0$ for **any** functionals in $X^*$ then $x-\tilde{x}=0$ which is equivalent to $x = \tilde{x}$

QED?

Comment: You have only shown $a = \tilde a$, which is not $x = \tilde x$.

Comment: $f$ must be a linear functional, so $f(x) = f(\tilde{x})$ yields $f(x - \tilde{x}) = 0$. It then follows from corollary (4.3.4 p.223 Kreyszig) that if $f(x - \tilde{x})=0$ for **all** functionals in $X^*$ then $x-\tilde{x}=0$ which is equivalent to $x = \tilde{x}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. This is a standard exercise and a well-known consequence of the Hahn Banach theorem. I suggest you vote to close this post as a duplicate.

Comment: @ArcticChar yes it almost does, the accepted answer there says that if $f(x)=x^*(x)=0$ for any linear functional, it must be so that $x=0$. This is needed to conclude the proof. However, I wanted to check if the first part of my proof makes sense. I have also attached partials of the proof in Kreyszig.